# VB Excel 2003 line spacing

Tags: excel, vba, vb6, excel-2003, office-automation

I'm programming VB Excel automation app which converts text to Excel.

How can U set linespacing for text in single row like in Word (`Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0`).

Are there any similar tips?

Comment: there's no such thing as Word `SpaceAfter` in Excel. If I correctly understand your aim, you can either insert blank rows and set their height to appropriately separated adjacent rows or simply set each row with text height and justify the text to the top. But Excel isn't a word processor and you'll much sooner hit some wall

Comment: thanks  user3598756 , nice trick ,but microsoft must do some updates

Comment: In truth I must add I have Excel 2013 so maybe Excel 2016 has some update on that side

Comment: Nope, it doesnt